# Sull'uso del verbo "paventare"

Tags: word-usage

Usando l'espressione *paventare un'ipotesi* ho controllato alcuni dizionari e in rete ho trovato che il mio dubbio era già stato espresso da altri.

È veramente scorretto l'uso di paventare nel senso di *avanzare, esporre*? Eppure sono sicuro che il termine viene usato in questo senso. Può essere considerata una mutazione semantica?

[Paventare](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/22-04-2010/paventare-1529776.html?refresh_ce-cp): (Corriere della Sera)

> - Il verbo "paventare" risulta, in tutti i vocabolari che ho avuto modo di consultare, un sinonimo di temere, aver paura, spaventarsi... Eppure viene comunemente usato come "prospettare". E non solo nel parlato: lo trovo continuamente,in articoli di giornale e scritti vari. Del resto basta digitare "paventare un'ipotesi" su un motore di ricerca e analizzare i risultati trovati, per accorgersi che non viene utilizzato come sinonimo di temere, bensì di prospettare. Perché? E' corretto? Se lo è, perché tale significato non è testimoniato dai dizionari?

[Paventare](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/per-aver-paura-usare-paventare): (Accademia della Crusca)

> - «Antonio Mattioli ci segnala usi a suo avviso impropri del verbo paventare. Gli sembra che soprattutto in ambito giornalistico il verbo venga usato come sinonimo di avere intenzione, avere in animo di (l'esempio riportato, purtroppo senza contesto, dal nostro lettore è "La Regione paventa la realizzazione di un nuovo ospedale").

Comment: Anche [qui](https://topgonzo.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/tra-dire-e-fare/) (cerca la parola "paventare") se ne parla.

Answer (score 6):

Non solo è sbagliato, ma è un esempio classico di errore, come “comminare” detto di quello che fa un giudice o una sentenza (è la legge che commina una pena, come previsione generale, non il giudice in uno specifico processo).

In entrambi i casi basta pensare all'etimologia. “Paventare”, come accenna una delle citazioni, è imparentato col latino *pavere* (a cui sono collegati anche “paura” e “spavento”), cioè “temere”: se io pavento un certo fatto, vuol dire che temo che si realizzi, spero di evitarlo, non certo che me lo auguro. Nell'altro senso si possono usare “proporre”, “prospettare”, “caldeggiare” etc.

(E “comminare” contiene la radice del latino *minari*, cioè “minacciare”. La legge “minaccia” certe pene a chi fosse intenzionato a commettere certe malefatte. Il giudice non minaccia un bel niente: il reato è stato commesso e lui condanna alla pena relativa.)

((Sempre a proposito di latinismi usati spesso male e in cui aiuta anche mnemonicamente aver presente l'etimo, un esercizio: se io “non mi perito” di fare una cosa, vuol dire che la faccio o che mi trattengo dal farla?))

Comment: Il fatto che sia comunemente usato non da nessun credito al diverso uso del termine? E poi, perché questo uso,'alternativo* ha preso piede? Io ho come l'impressione che sia usato più in questa accezione che in quella più corretta.

Comment: È vero, le parole cambiano di significato nel corso del tempo, ma secondo me qui siamo ben lontani dal dare per acquisito il nuovo significato del termine, non fosse altro che per il fatto che, visto che i due significati sono praticamente opposti, se accettassimo anche quello “nuovo” non sapremmo più che cosa si sta dicendo. È una prospettiva che pavento... :-)

Comment: "*Paventare un'ipotesi*"  è comunque un'espressione che si sente spesso. Diciamo che è un'espressione idiomatica?

Comment: Nel senso di “sperare che l'ipotesi si realizzi” o “sperare che non si realizzi”?

Comment: Nel senso di "avanzare" un'ipotesi.

Comment: Non ce l'ho presente, ma non ne dubito. Io non lo capirei.

Comment: @Gio: Paventare un'ipotesi per me significa temere che il fatto ipotizzato si realizzi. Potresti fare un esempio concreto in cui "paventare un'ipotesi" viene usato con il significato di "avanzare un'ipotesi"?

Answer (score -3):

No, non è scorretto, è solo che ha un significato diverso da 'esporre/presentare/fare/ideare ... un'ipotesi'.

Si usa infatti 'paventare' quando si ritiene che l'ipotesi oggetto di paventazione:

- sia sbagliata a priori, o perché la persona che la paventa è incapace di fare ipotesi o perché l'ipotesi—nell'intendimento del paventante—persegue in sé finalità autodimostrative di una tesi la cui dimostrazione sarebbe, invece, tutta da verificare;
- ponga un problema critico nel contesto in cui è espressa.

That's all.

Comment: Scusa  ma non è chiaro cosa vuoi dire. ***Paventazione***  non esiste come termine, ma a parte questo non capisco cosa tu voglia dire con "*persegue in sé finalità autodimostrative di una tesi la cui dimostrazione sarebbe tutta da verificare, oppure ponga un problema critico nel contesto in cui è espressa."*. Probably you may find it easier  to  express your concept in English.

Comment: Non capisco niente di niente.

Comment: @Charo, l'ho messa meglio ora, forse aiuta.

Comment: A parte che anche a me non è chiara la risposta (ma può essere un problema mio), trovo una certa circolarità nello spiegare il senso della parola “paventare” usando la parola “paventare” (e derivati).