# Questo uso del verbo "peritarsi" è oggigiorno generalmente accettato?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

Ho letto il contenuto della voce ["peritarsi" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/peritarsi) e ho avuto la sensazione che non corrispondesse del tutto con gli usi di questo verbo in cui mi sono imbattuta io.

La prima cosa che mi ha un po' stupita è la marca d'uso "lett.": credo di averlo incontrato in contesti non letterari,  usato, per esempio, da qualche persona che si rivolge a un altra in una conversazione comune.

Poi, ecco i diversi significati di questo verbo secondo questo dizionario:

> Esitare a compiere un'azione, per mancanza di volontà o di decisione, o anche per timidezza, soggezione, senso di vergogna, o per altro motivo di ritrosia

> Più spesso, spec. in frasi negative, avere dubbî, incertezze, farsi scrupolo di fare qualcosa o di comportarsi in un determinato modo

> Meno com., provare timore, sentirsi a disagio, non fidarsi, e sim.

Tuttavia, l'uso di "peritarsi" che personalmente ho trovato qualche volta è simile a quello che si fa in questo passo tratto da una [discussione su Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussione:Soka_Gakkai) (grassetto mio):

> Bene, io ti contesto il fatto di NON esserti sforzato a seguire un METODO INTELLETTUALMENTE ONESTO e aver fatto prevalere i tuoi PREGIUDIZI in questa voce. Quando lo hai fatto?
>
> - [...]
> - [...]
> - Quando io ho inserito alcuni riferimenti sul Komeito ripresi dalla Wiki inglese tu hai giustamente ricordato che essa riporta "This article does not cite any references or sources" ma **non ti sei peritato** di verificare le altre fonti prese da altre "parti" [...].

Un altro esempio si trova in questo [articolo di Diego Fusaro](https://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2018/10/14/ecco-come-mi-hanno-censurato-in-prima-serata-su-rai-3/4692434/) per il blog del *Fatto quotidiano* (grassetto mio):

> È la cifra del “si dice" impersonale e di una chiacchiera che resta sempre sulla superficie di ogni cosa. Senza **peritarsi** di
> approfondire. Rivelando come di fatto operano molti di coloro i quali impropriamente si definiscono giornalisti: e che meglio andrebbero appellati nichilisti che non credono in nulla e parlano di tutto, sempre compattamente seguendo – sia chiaro – le correnti del politicamente
> corretto.

E su questo [articolo del *Corriere della Sera*](https://www.corriere.it/spettacoli/12_febbraio_22/ruggeri-disco-flop-cruccu_0cdd8616-5d7a-11e1-8d58-29f34aaed5a4.shtml) si può leggere (anche qui il grassetto è mio):

> «Vendite fantastiche, strabilianti, il disco è al primo posto a un giorno dalla sua uscita»: gli uffici stampa son soliti urlare, così ai quattro venti, i numeri dell'album appena uscito del loro artista X. Nessuno che **si periti** di andare a controllare, mentre il suddetto artista è costretto a confermare i roboanti annunci dei suoi addetti.

Anche sul sito [diritto.it](https://www.diritto.it/il-noleggio-tentativo-di-chiarezza-sostanziale-e-terminologica/) (grassetto mio):

> Una grossa anomalia, è rappresentata dal concetto di noleggio: mai una fattispecie contrattuale così specifica e, come vedremo, così controversa, è stata oggetto di uso indiscriminato e generalizzato non solo nel linguaggio comune ma anche tra gli operatori commerciali specializzati e, cosa decisamente più grave, fra gli stessi operatori del diritto, fino ad arrivare ad un uso improprio del termine (e questo ci sembra davvero inammissibile) da parte dei giudici di merito e della stessa Corte di Cassazione (sostenuto il numero delle sentenze: si citano, a titolo di esempio: Trib. Milano, 3 novembre 2004; Cass. Pen., sez. III, 23 aprile 2003, n°26176; Corte App. Perugia, 18 maggio 1999), nonché dello stesso legislatore: quest’ultimo, nel corso dei decenni fino ai giorni nostri, mai **si è peritato** di dettare un’organica disciplina contrattuale per concetti quali, ad esempio, il “noleggio di autoveicolo”, aumentando gli equivoci e le problematiche a tutto ciò sottese: solo per fare qualche citazione, dagli svariati “codici della strada” che si sono succeduti nel tempo, al d.p.r. 28 giugno 1955, n° 771, alla l. 24 dicembre 1969, n° 990 (es.: l’art. 6 comma 2 d.lgs 19 settembre 1994, n°626), tutti hanno contribuito a confondere, tramite qualificazioni parziali, contraddizioni ed eliminazioni, il già molto fumoso concetto di noleggio di autoveicolo.

E in un recente [articolo del quotidiano *Il tempo*](https://www.iltempo.it/politica/2020/05/30/news/coronavirus-colpe-governo-inchiesta-corte-dei-conti-giuseppe-conte-roberto-speranza-bechis-22959987/) si trova (grassetto mio):

> Non c’era speranza quando il virus è arrivato perché per lunghe settimane (più di un mese) il governo non **si è peritato** di fare gli approvvigionamenti necessari (guanti, mascherine, camici e varie protezioni del personale medico e infermieristico), che spettavano allo Stato attraverso la Consip e non alle Regioni.

Persino sulla [rivista *Ecdotica*](https://www.fundacionaquae.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Ecdotica-12.pdf) (a "peer reviewed journal"), si può leggere (grassetto mio):

> Si tratta, in effetti, dei due episodi principali – il ragguaglio di Barbi e lo studio della Ageno – che nel ’900 costellano la ricerca su Sacchetti, dopo di che il lavoro critico sul testo sembra di fatto arenarsi, malgrado le diverse edizioni con pretese critiche che si sono succedute nel Novecento, e di cui ho già fatto menzione: talora finte edizioni critiche, direi, che, compresa quella di Marucci, non **si peritano** di esaminare l’intera tradizione dando fede in chiave evangelica a Barbi e al gruppo B e in genere ricorrendo alla *varia lectio* disponibile in modo desultorio.

Quindi, sembra si tratti di un uso abbastanza diffuso.

Ora, questo uso non sembra combaciare con nessuna delle definizioni del dizionario sopra riportate. Dal contesto, ho sempre pensato che "non ti sei peritato di", "senza peritarsi di", "mai si è peritato di", ecc. in frasi come queste significasse più o meno "non ti sei presso la briga di" (o "non ti sei preoccupato di"), "senza prendersi la briga di", "mai si è preso la briga di", ecc.: è così?

Ho cercato in altri dizionari e le definizioni sono simili. Si tratta di un nuovo uso del verbo "peritarsi" generalmente accettato? O è semplicemente una parola che, per qualche ragione, si usa spesso male?

Comment: Sì, è uno di quei verbi spesso usati male, in questo caso al contrario del loro vero significato. Alcuni lo usano impropriamente come se significasse “prendersi la briga” o simili, e di fatto mettono un “non” di troppo. Un altro esempio di verbo usato a volte male è “paventare”, usato da alcuni come se significasse “prospettare, prendere in esame” (“paventare una possibilità” per dire semplicemente “esporla, metterla sul tavolo”).

Comment: Se posso dire una cosa sgradevole, secondo me succede a chi cerca di usare un lessico un po' al di sopra di ciò che padroneggia senza problemi, e così facendo si tende delle trappole e ci cade da solo.

Comment: @DaG: Di questo uso di "paventare" se n'era parlato [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5631/). Ah! E adesso ho visto che nella tua risposta a quella domanda hai anche menzionato "peritarsi".

Comment: Ah, è vero! In effetti sono fra i miei “pet peeve”.

Comment: Non conosco quel sito di diritto, ma gli altri esempi vengono dalla Wikipedia italiana e dai quotidiani, che non sono esattamente i maggiori depositari della cultura linguistica italiana. Sarebbe interessante vedere se c'è, per esempio, qualche vero scrittore che usa “peritare” nel modo sbagliat... nuovo.

Comment: Una mia personale ipotesi su perché sia tanto diffuso questo errore è perché in italiano molti altri verbi e locuzioni con significati affini si costruiscono appunto con il “non” (non si prende la briga di, non fa lo sforzo di, non si dà pena di, non si preoccupa di, non gli importa di, non gliene frega di...).

Comment: Spero le vostre risposte che saranno sicuramente migliori di quella che ho scritto io.

Comment: Adesso che questa domanda è riapparsa, @DaG, questi usi "sbagliati" di un vocabolo a volte finiscono per imporsi: vedi quello che spiega Pérez-Reverte (scrittore e membro della RAE) sull'evoluzione del senso di "álgido" nella lingua spagnola nel post intitolato "De muy frío a muy caliente". Oggi poca gente sa che "álgido" può significare "molto freddo": l'aggettivo si usa quasi esclusivamente in senso figurato per riferirsi a un "tema caldo". Non so però se questo tipo di trasformazione del significato è quello che sta accadendo con "peritarsi": forse la domanda della Treccani è un po' vecchia

Comment: Il link al blog di Pérez-Reverte: https://arturoperez-reverte.blogspot.com/2019/07/?m=1.

Comment: Certo, @Charo, tutto l'italiano è un [latino “sbagliato”](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appendix_Probi), in un certo senso, e più concretamente l'italiano (come senz'altro tutte le lingue) è pieno di usi “sbagliati” che poi sono diventati la norma (iniziare/cominciare, ossia/ovvero, lastrico, ...), ma in casi come questo, dove è tuttora chiaro quale sia l'uso “corretto” (come anche per “piuttosto che”, “settimana prossima” etc.), non sappiamo se l'“errore” diventerà una nuova norma e non vedo perché adottarlo prematuramente.

Comment: Sì, @DaG: mi fa dubitare il fatto che l'unica risposta alla domanda che c'è in questo momento non sia convincente (non ho idea di perché).

Comment: @DaG: A proposito, quello che mi sembra un po' diverso dell'uso "sbagliato" del "piuttosto che" è che inizialmente fosse limitato "agli usi colti dei settentrionali" (veramente io questo non lo sapevo fino a poco tempo fa e non so se si dovrebbe considerare come un uso regionale).

Answer (score 1):

Ho trovato una domanda al riguardo sul [sito web di domande e risposte della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_105.html).

La conclusione che se ne può trarre è che le persone che usano il verbo "peritarsi" nel modo esemplificato nella domanda, in realtà, stanno dicendo il contrario di quello che intendono: la risposta della Treccani spiega che, nell'italiano moderno, la frase

> «non mi sono peritato di controllare»,

ad esempio, ha il

> significato di ‘non ho avuto incertezze (dubbi) nel controllare (nello svolgere il controllo)’.

Prendendo, per esempio, il passo tratto dalla discussione su Wikipedia citata nella domanda, quando si dice a qualcuno "non ti sei peritato di verificare le altre fonti", si sta affermando che quella persona non ha avuto nessuna incertezza, nessun dubbio  nel verificare le altri fonti, cioè, ha verificato le altre fonti senza esitare a farlo. Ma è chiaro dal contesto che chi ha scritto la frase in realtà vuol esprimere il contrario: "non ti sei preso la briga di verificare le altri fonti".

Ecco la domanda sul sito della Treccani:

> *Durante una conversazione di lavoro ho pronunciato la seguente affermazione: «mi sono peritato di controllare...», volendo intendere "ho controllato", "mi sono fatto carico di stimare, di periziare...". A questo punto, un collega ha sottolineato che l'utilizzo di tale verbo era errato, in quanto il corretto significato di "peritato" sarebbe "esitare... non osare" (dal verbo "peritarsi"). Desidererei sapere se l'espressione da me utilizzata è da ritenersi corretta*.

E questa è la risposta:

> Il verbo *peritarsi* (dal latino *pigritari* ‘essere pigro’) è attestato nell’italiano scritto a partire dal XIV secolo. Significa, secondo quanto propone il *Vocabolario della lingua italiana* Treccani, «esitare a compiere un’azione, per mancanza di volontà o di decisione, o anche per timidezza, soggezione, senso di vergogna, o per altro motivo di ritrosia». Di sapore letterario, *peritarsi* viene oggi più spesso adoperato in frasi negative nel senso attenuato di «avere dubbi, incertezze, farsi scrupolo di fare qualcosa o di comportarsi in un determinato modo» (Treccani). 
>
> Perciò la frase «mi sono peritato di controllare» risulterebbe, più che sgrammaticata, inusuale (essendo affermativa e non negativa) e, in ogni caso, significherebbe «ho esitato a controllare», facendo intuire che il controllo non è stato poi fatto. Più comune sarebbe la frase «non mi sono peritato di controllare», nel significato di ‘non ho avuto incertezze (dubbi) nel controllare (nello svolgere il controllo)’.

Può darsi che l'utilizzo di "peritarsi" esemplificato nella domanda si stia diffondendo, ma questa risposta della Treccani ci fa capire che non si tratta di un uso generalmente accettato.   La persona che fa la domanda chiede se "mi sono peritato di controllare..." può voler dire "ho controllato", "mi sono fatto carico di stimare, di periziare..." e nella risposta si afferma chiaramente che questo non è il significato comunemente accettato, ma che significherebbe invece "ho esitato a controllare" e farebbe pensare che il controllo non si è fatto.

Infine, ecco un esempio di uso proprio di "peritarsi" (cioè, in accordo con le definizioni dei dizionari) tratto del libro *La concessione del telefono* di Andrea Camilleri (grassetto mio):

> Come lei ben sa, tutto è cominciato una ventina d’anni orsono con la sciagurata inchiesta promossa in Sicilia da Franchetti e Sonnino, inchiesta che l’illuminato Rosario Conti ebbe a definire «uno spaventevole attentato all’Unità e all’Indipendenza dell’Italia» e che il quotidiano palermitano «Il Precursore» **non si peritò** di bollare come «opera pericolosissima perché ha messo avanti la questione sociale attizzando così la guerra civile e la guerra sociale».

Il significato sarebbe che questo quotidiano non esitò a qualificare negativamente questa inchiesta come «opera pericolosissima [...]».

Comment: Da tempo cercavo se si trovava qualche informazione su questo uso improprio di "peritarsi" in rete. Fino a oggi non sono riuscita a trovare nulla al riguardo. Devo anche dire che i commenti di @DaG mi hanno aiutato a capire che si tratta in effetti di un uso improprio: quando postai la domanda (nella sua prima versione) questo non  mi era per niente chiaro (chiedevo semplicemente: "cosa significa *peritarsi* quando si usa in questo modo? Non mi sembra che quello che riportano i dizionari abbia senso in questi contesti").

Comment: Insisto: spero le vostre risposte. Io ho scritto questo perché, in molto tempo, è l'unico che sono riuscita a trovare al riguardo.