# Come si usa l'espressione "con buona pace di"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Si tratta di una domanda correlata a [questa altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13180).

Nel post che ho appena citato, ho riportato le definizioni dell'espressione "con buona pace di" che si trovano su parecchi dizionari.

Malgrado queste spiegazioni, non mi è chiaro come si usa di solito questa locuzione. Quindi, gradirei di avere alcuni esempi di uso.

Ne ho trovato alcuni sul [sito dell’Associazione Culturale Italiano Semplicemente](https://italianosemplicemente.com/2018/02/11/con-buona-pace/). Tuttavia, questo sito è stato citato in alcune risposte e commenti e, dalle critiche che ha ricevuto, mi è sembrato capire che non tutto quello che riporta è veramente affidabile.

A continuazione, cerco di farne qualcuno io stessa, ma non sono per niente sicura che questo sia il modo in cui si utilizza questa locuzione: è per questa ragione che posto la domanda.

Primo esempio. Luigi ha detto: "Non ti sei peritata di controllare le fonti di questo articolo".

Ho sempre pensato che Luigi si esprima spesso usando parole e espressioni complicate per dare a intendere di avere una padronanza della lingua al di sopra di quella dei comuni mortali. Infatti, il verbo "peritarsi" usato in questo modo è uno dei suoi preferiti.

Allora io dico con ironia nei riguardi di Luigi: "Con buona pace di Luigi, chi usa *peritarsi di* intendendo *prendersi la briga di* lo fa perché cerca di usare un lessico un po' al di sopra di ciò che padroneggia senza problemi, e così facendo si tende delle trappole e ci cade da solo" (ho preso da [questo commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12849/questo-uso-del-verbo-peritarsi-%c3%a8-oggigiorno-generalmente-accettato#comment30163_12849) di @DaG).

Secondo esempio. Maria, che si vanta sempre di essere un'esperta di letteratura, dice: "L'ultimo romanzo di Mario Corti<sup>1</sup> è un capolavoro. Si tratta senza dubbio di un testo che passerà alla storia della letteratura universale".

La mia opinione è che con questa e altre  affermazioni dimostri di non capire un'acca di letteratura e colgo l'occasione per farlo evidente pronunciando questa frase: "Con buona pace di Maria, ho letto l'ultimo romanzo di Mario Corti e vi posso assicurare che è davvero brutto".

È così che si usa di solito l'espressione "con buona pace di"?

<sup>1. Si tratta di un nome inventato.</sup>

Comment: Io direi che in generale non ci siamo molto. Le frasi sono accettabili, più la seconda della prima, però mancano d'ironia e di mordente, che si ottiene sottolineando il contrasto con un principio dato per assodato e autorevole. Tanto per dire, se invece di Maria si parlasse, che so, di Umberto Eco, allora la frase avrebbe quel mordente che ora manca, perché si contraddirebbe un'opinione ritenuta importante.

Comment: Va bene: questa è la ragione per cui ho bisogno di una risposta con esempi più calzanti.

Comment: «sito dell’Associazione Culturale Italiano Semplicemente ... non tutto quello che riporta è veramente affidabile» - Confermo: lo stile in generale fa sorridere, alcune delle spiegazioni sono imprecise e, infine, impareresti l'italiano da uno che scrive “Facciamo un altro esempio che lo prendo direttamente da Google news”?

Comment: @Hachi:     Non si usa l'aggettivo *cattivo* per qualificare un libro, un film, uno spettacolo, ecc.?

Comment: OK, @Hachi: ho cambiato "cattivo" con "brutto", ma forse dovrei porre una domanda sull'uso di "cattivo".

Comment: Lascia pure cattivo, il significato è comprensibile. Forse suona strano a me.

Comment: Se quel sito web non è veramente affidabile, non sarebbe utile avere qualche esempio più calzante su Italian.SE? (tra l'altro, dal commento di linuxfan, personalmente mi sono accorta di non aver capito proprio nulla).

Comment: I tuoi esempi vanno benissimo. Credo che quello che voleva sottolineare @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica fosse semplicemente che “con buona pace di X”, che di per sé vuol dire “senza offendere X” e simili, di fatto è usato quasi sempre in modo ironico, quasi a dire “chi se ne frega di quel che pensa X” o addirittura “X si crede chissà chi”.

Comment: @DaG:  Quindi, i miei esempi vanno bene, ma "con buona pace di" si usa molto più spesso in un modo diverso?

Comment: Dipende: se il senso è, tra l'altro, di lanciare una frecciatina ironica nei confronti di Luigi o di Maria, vanno benone. Se è solo di constatare la differenza tra la tua opinione e la loro, sono corretti ma forse verrebbe più spontaneo scegliere qualche altra formulazione.

Comment: @dag, sì, il meccanismo degli esempi è giusto: lanciano frecciatine, solo un po' deboli. Riguardo a "cattivo", suonava male nella frase originaria, ma "cattivo romanzo" è un po' meglio. Gli aggettivi cambiano abbastanza se spostati prima/dopo il nome.

Comment: Insisto: se questo è così, penso sarebbe utile avere una risposta con esempi più calzanti. Poi... magari dovrò veramente porre una domanda su come si usa "cattivo".

Comment: Va bene, @DaG: siccome la domanda è senza risposta, da quello che ho capito dai commenti, cerco di migliorare i miei esempi aggiungendo qualche particolare. Vediamo se ci riesco.

Comment: Altra piccola nota...”E’ così ***che*** si usa l’espressione?” Non “È così come...”

Comment: Ah! Ho appena visto i voti ai commenti di linuxfan che sono apparsi recentemente (non c'erano quando ho fatto la mia ultima modifica al post): quindi la conclusione è che non riesco a capire del tutto bene come si usa questa espressione, per cui una risposta sarebbe davvero utile. @DaG: credo di non aver colto del tutto il senso del tuo ultimo commento perché i miei esempi sono ancora "deboli" e "non ci siamo molto" :(

Comment: @Charo: Mi sembra che linuxfan si limiti semplicemente a confermare quello che stiamo dicendo tutti, che l'uso di “con buona pace di” è spesso ironico.

Comment: Sì, @DaG, e che gli esempi che ho cercato di fare non sono sufficientemente ironici in confronto  all'uso che di solito si fa dell'espressione.

Comment: Non ti preoccupare, @Charo, i tuoi sono esempi che si potrebbero tranquillamente trovare in un normale discorso di un italiano. “Ironico” significa semplicemente che quello che si dice non va preso alla lettera.