# Differenze fra "quale" e "cosa"

Tags: difference, adjectives, pronouns, interrogatives

For example, there is a sentence in the textbook *Nuovo Progetto Italiano*:

> Osservate le due immagini e dite quali differenze esistono.

Can I use "cosa" instead here? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that *quale* is an (interrogative) adjective, so it need a noun to which it refers (*quale strada?*, *quali libri?*...), while *cosa* – besides being a noun meaning “thing” – is a (interrogative) pronoun, so it stands in place of a noun, the object of the question: *cosa vuoi?* It's pretty much the same difference as between “which” (*quale*) and “what” (*cosa*).

You may also use *che* or *che cosa*, rather than *cosa*.

So, if you were to rephrase your example with *cosa*, you might want to say, for instance:

> Osservate le due immagini e dite in (che) cosa differiscono

i.e., “...in what they differ”.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. *Quali* is an adjective, referring to the noun *differenze*, and both together refer to the verb *esistono*.

If you substitute *quali* with *cose* you have two nouns, *cose* e *differenze*, without a connection between them and to the verb.

You could use instead say, dropping *differenze*:

> [...] e dite *cosa* è diverso (not fully correct)
> [...] e dite che *cosa* è diverso (better)
> [...] e dite *quali cose* sono diverse (also good)

Comment: Good, but _cosa_ in the first sentence is not a noun, but an interrogative pronoun, and as such it is fully part of “correct”, modern Italian; it was largely used by Manzoni in his _Promessi Sposi_ (see Serianni, VII.256).

Comment: What do you mean by “recall”?

Comment: @dag Manzoni was also used to write things like "Facciamo un altro esempio che lo prendo direttamente da Google news" (from a comment of yours to this question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/come-si-usa-lespressione-con-buona-pace-di). About "recall", yes it is not the perfect word to use there. I'll change it.

Comment: If you don't have access to Serianni's book, you can also read this [article from Treccani grammar](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/cosa-o-che-cosa-che_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/).

Comment: @linuxfan, could you provide an actual example if that construction in Manzoni? I'm interested since, though not advisable to an Italian learner, it's somewhat frequent in colloquial Italian.

Comment: @dag: https://www.avvenire.it/agora/pagine/parole
  Già  lo faceva Manzoni (pensiamo ai suoi famosi anacoluti)...

https://www.sololibri.net/Anacoluto-significato-ed-esempi.html
  Anche Manzoni ne era affascinato tanto da utilizzare l'anacoluto nel suo romanzo più famoso...

http://treccani.it/enciclopedia/anacoluto_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/
  Molto noti, al proposito, gli anacoluti nei Promessi Sposi

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacoluto
  ...sono noti gli anacoluti di Machiavelli e quelli, disseminati ne I promessi sposi...

Comment: @charo your link describes *cosa* with "*cosa*, considerata dai grammatici una forma da evitarsi" ("regarded by grammaticians as a form to avoid"). I don't say to avoid it, I've just said that it is not *fully* correct, implying that something fully correct has no debates on it.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: This is not what the article I mentioned really says. The grammarians you are referring to are from long time ago!   By the way, I won't say the construction you mentioned is an anacoluthon.

Comment: @charo, I simply reported what the article says, and it does not say "antique grammarians" or similar things. You can think I refer to them (you can think whatever you want), but the article plainly says what I've cited.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: This sentence is from a section referring to history of language! It says: "La forma che nella storia dell’italiano si è affermata più tardi è stata proprio *cosa*, considerata dai grammatici una forma da evitarsi. La fortuna di *cosa* è cominciata alla metà dell’Ottocento, quando Manzoni – seguendo il modello del fiorentino parlato dalle persone colte – corresse in *cosa* i *che cosa* usati nella prima edizione dei *Promessi sposi*."     It refers to grammarians from the XIX century!

Comment: So what, @charo? How can you infer that, in the article, the word "grammatici" refers to the ancient grammaticians instead of the modern ones? I have no doubt you can find someone else saying that "cosa" instead of "che cosa" is totally correct. Find that source and post it here, the link you posted does not say what you are saying.

Comment: @linuxfan: It's said at the beginning of the article: "CHE, COSA O CHE COSA? Tutte e tre le forme del pronome interrogativo cosiddetto ‘neutro’ sono corrette e ampiamente diffuse nell’italiano contemporaneo nelle proposizioni interrogative sia dirette, sia indirette: **Che** / **cosa** / **che cosa** mi volevi dire? // Non mi ricordo più di **che** / di **cosa** / di **che cosa** ti volevo parlare. // *Cosa* appare oggi la forma più comune in tutti i livelli dello scritto e del parlato, ma [...]".

Comment: Grazie, @linuxfan. Conosci anche esempi manzoniani al di fuori dei dialoghi (come tutti quelli citati nell'Enciclopedia dell'italiano), che servono a caratterizzare il parlato dei personaggi più che l'italiano quale è usato dall'autore?

Comment: To confirm the fact that the condemnation of _cosa_ by grammarians is referred to past ones, Serianni's _Italiano_ literally says: “_Cosa_ invece di _che_ fu spesso osteggiato dai grammatici del secolo scorso (= XIX sec., since Serianni was writing in the 1990s), ma si diffuse ampiamente grazie al largo impiego fattone dal Manzoni nell'edizione definitiva dei _Promessi Sposi_”. So: language evolves; if ever, _cosa_ as an interrogative pronoun could be reproached (and even then on flimsy bases) some 150+ years ago.

Comment: @dag, non saprei: il romanzo lo lessi decine di anni fa (non ricordo neppure come finisce). Ricordo che era ben scorrevole, e che usava un italiano molto "normale" considerata l'età.

Comment: Grazie, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica, ma ho ben presente lo stile dei _Promessi Sposi_. Speravo che, visto che mi avevi ripreso su certe segnalazioni, ne fossi un conoscitore. Lo trovi normale perché l'italiano di Manzoni (non dei dialoghi dei personaggi, caratterizzati in vario modo come popolani, colti, affettati etc.) è in buona misura il nostro italiano, in parte perché è stato spesso preso a modello, in parte – cosa più importante – perché Manzoni, proprio in quanto il fiorentino (cioè, de facto, l'italiano standard) non era la sua lingua madre, ne svolse uno studio approfonditissimo.

Comment: @dag siamo d'accordo. Voglio precisare che il mio primo commento non voleva criticare il Manzoni, solo sottolineare che Manzoni usava (con ottimi motivi) anche un italiano men che perfetto. Se poi certe parole o costrutti fossero ben accetti o meno, a quell'epoca e dopo, è un altro discorso. A me per esempio il *cosa* senza *che* infastidisce, e non sono (o fui) solo, in questo.